# Error when using Sequelize.query, is the query not case sensitive?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I get an error when running this query with Sequelize.query:

`sequelize.query(
        "SELECT hubs.* FROM hubs LEFT JOIN posts ON hubs.id = posts.hubId WHERE 
         posts.userId = ? GROUP BY hubs.id ORDER BY COUNT(posts.id) 
         DESC LIMIT 3",
    {
        replacements: [userId],
        type: QueryTypes.SELECT
    }
)`

When i run it I get an error saying:

```
error: column posts.hubid does not exist
hint: 'Perhaps you meant to reference the column "posts.hubId"
```

As you can se in my query i have written posts.hubId and not posts.hubid as the error says. The hint is exactly how i have writeen my query. It seems to me like the query i wrote is not case-sensitive or what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar error trying to execute:

`sequelize.query("DROP ENUM enum_table_enumName;")`

What solved it for me was:

```
sequelize.query(
  "DROP ENUM public.\"enum_table_enumName\";", 
  {
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.DELETE 
  }
);
```

Note: `public` is the schema name (default schema).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, postgreSQL is case sensitive. You have to write `posts.hubId` in `"` using `\` or `'`. The updated query:

```
sequelize.query(
    "SELECT hubs.* FROM hubs LEFT JOIN posts ON hubs.id = \"posts.hubId\" WHERE 
     posts.userId = ? GROUP BY hubs.id ORDER BY COUNT(posts.id) 
     DESC LIMIT 3",
{
    replacements: [userId],
    type: QueryTypes.SELECT
})
```